# Bootstrap: how show panel over google maps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3 i want show a google maps and a bootstrap panel over the map.

So i have the following html section:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%"; height:"100vh";></div>
    <div class="panel col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
       ....
       ....
    <div>
</div>
```

The panel anyway is showed below the maps and not over the maps.

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you using any custom CSS or is just this OOTB bootstrap code you are using?

Comment: vh is not working on safari mobile, better use absolute positioning and `top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;` for `#map-canvas`

Answer (score 0):

Custom Css , For example

```
.container-fluid{
    position: relative;
}
#map-canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.panel{
    z-index: 2;
}
```